# App metadata seems non editable in iTunes connect?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

i have added a build to an existing app as update. The build was uploaded successfully and i selected it and saved. When I moved to next screen for submission there was some options related to encryption. Then I made some selections, but was not sure about it. So I just logged out the account without selecting next/save. But currently the app is in **Prepare for Submission** state , but the meta data seems non editable. Also the Save & Submit for Review options seems missing !!!!!!!

Comment: Did you try to clear your browser cache? This might work.

Comment: @ChengYuHsu Didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer by myself. My user account credential had been changed by admin unknowingly. So I lost credential to submit app. When my admin gave me back those credentials to my account the submit and save buttons became visible and I did submit.